# Gridlayout does not fill_parent evenly - Android / Java

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-gridlayout

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening but I've created a GridLayout in Android and it does not fill_parent evenly as expected. Most of the icons are smushed to the left - and are not evenly distributed.

Can anyone spot why this might be happening?

### Screenshot:

[image]

### XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/download"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_ListView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingBottom="65dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingBottom="65dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/boxart"
            android:layout_width="450dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="65dp" />

         <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_ListView2a"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="450dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:columnCount="5"
                android:columnWidth="300dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="100dip"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:rowCount="6"
                android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
                android:verticalSpacing="100dip" >

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch1"

                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:layout_row="3" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch2"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:layout_row="3" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch3"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:layout_row="3" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="5"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_shopping" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="5"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_superfan" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch4"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:layout_row="3" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_quotes" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_plotinfo" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_locations" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_dilemmas" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_vehicles_top_center" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_weapons_top_center" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="5"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_recipe" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="5"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_trivia" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch8"
                    android:layout_column="4"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:layout_row="5" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch7"
                    android:layout_column="3"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:layout_row="5" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch6"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:layout_row="5" />

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/switch5"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:layout_row="5" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_music_top_center" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_who_top_center" />

            </GridLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="On Demand"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/timeline_bottom_android"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backbtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_back_arrow" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/backButtonTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/saveButton"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Movies"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"`     should be `android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"` for imageView9 (etc)